# Uninitialized constant while trying to include helper module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, padrino

The module that I am trying to include is located here:
test/unit/helpers/test_helpers.rb

Looks like:

```
module TestHelpers
end
```

I am trying to include it in:
test/unit/app/models/abc.rb

```
class Abc < ActiveSupport::TestCase
include TestHelpers
end
```

gives the following error:

> Error executing test/unit/app/models/abc.rb uninitialized constant
>   Abc::TestHelpers

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: the helper isn't included into ruby include tree... include it with `::require`

Answer (score 7):

To include a module into your class, you need to require that file.

> `require 'test_helpers'`

Add this line at the top of your model class.